# Determine whether the user selected Refresh in WebBrowser Control

Tags: webbrowser-control, autohotkey, beforenavigate2

How can I detect if the user selected `Refresh` via the context menu? The `NavigateComplete2` method does not get invoked when the user selects it.

More importantly, to set own custom user agent, one way to do it is to hook the `BeforeNavigate2` event method and it is necessary to know if the user has selected Refresh or navigating a new url.

Any insight would be appreciated.

This demonstrates the `NavigateComplete2` method does not get fired when `Refresh` is selected.

```
oWB := new WebBrowserControl("http://stackoverflow.com")
Class WebBrowserControl
{

    __New(strURL) { 
        static WB
        Gui, New, Resize 
        Gui, Add, ActiveX, vWB w780 h580, Shell.Explorer  
        Gui, show, w800 h600

        ComObjConnect(WB, this) 

        WB.Navigate(strURL)
        Loop
           Sleep 10
        Until (WB.readyState=4 && WB.document.readyState="complete" && !WB.busy)    
        Return
        GuiClose:
        ExitApp
    }

    NavigateComplete2(oParams*) {
        ComObjError(false)  
        WB := oParams[1]
        msgbox, 64, Navigate Completed
            , % "WB.locationURL :`t`t" WB.locationURL "`n"
            . "WB.Document.URL:`t`t" WB.Document.URL "`n"
            . "windowlocation.href:`t" WB.document.parentWindow.location.href
    }

    BeforeNavigate2(oParams*) {

        WB := oParams[8]
        strURL := oParams[2]        

        msgbox % "Loading URL:`t`t" strURL "`n"
            . "WB.locationURL :`t`t" WB.locationURL "`n"
            . "WB.Document.URL:`t`t" WB.Document.URL "`n"
            . "location.href:`t`t" WB.document.parentWindow.location.href "`n"
            . "WB.ReadyState:`t`t" WB.readystate "`n"
            . "WB.document.readystate:`t" WB.document.readystate "`n"
            . "WB.Busy:`t`t`t" WB.Busy "`n"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to see if a refresh (or new page) has been initiated is to monitor the mouse state (in Chrome, not sure about other browsers) with: if/while (A_Cursor = "AppStarting"). This is true when the mouse cursor has turned into an hourglass.

Comparing the previous and the new URL would tell you if this is a new request or a refresh: ControlGetText CurrentURL, Chrome_OmniboxView1, Chrome

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm talking about the AutoHotkey WebBrowser control. In other words, the GUI ActiveX control, not a regular browser like Google Chrome. It's not necessary to use `ControlGetText` to retrieve the loading url since the parameter of `BeforeNavigate2` captures it. However, it does not tell the difference between whether the user clicked a link or selected Refresh.

Comment: +1 for a really clever hack. I hope no one does this in production but props :)